# RoR | how to find the next and previous based on a date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to look up 1 instance of a model via a slug, which I can do via

```
@project = Project.where(:slug => params[:id]).first
```

But once I get the instance I want to find the next and previous instances of the model from a order of a column called publish which is a date.

how would I get the slug only of the previous and next instance of my arbitrary order by column?

::Edit::
 Adding this to my modeled worked.

```
def previous(offset = 0)     
  self.class.select('slug').first(:conditions => ['published < ?', self.id], :limit => 1,        :offset => offset, :order => "published DESC")
end

def next(offset = 0)
  self.class.select('slug').first(:conditions => ['published > ?', self.id], :limit => 1, :offset => offset, :order => "published ASC")
end
```

I found this solution at [Next, Previous Records Using Named Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754810/next-previous-records-using-named-scope)

Comment: What do you need? Next and last or next and previous?

Comment: Sorry Mischa I may have confused the questions. I'm looking to get the next and previous instances in relationship to one that is initially queried. the initial instance has no idea of its relation to the other instances. The order is based on one column in the model called published which is a date.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your `publish` dates are unique something like this ought to work:

```
@project = Project.where(:slug => params[:id]).first

@prev_project = Project.where( "publish < ?", @project.publish ).
                        order( "publish DESC" ).
                        first

@next_project = Project.where( "publish > ?", @project.publish ).
                        order( "publish" ).
                        first
```

For `@prev_project` the `where` clause indicates all Projects before `@project`, the `order` lists them latest first (which puts the one right before `@project` at the top) and `first` limits the query to one result, i.e. the previous Project. The query for `@next_project` is the same but reversed. If `publish` isn't unique you'll have to sort on a second criterium as well.

However, you may want to consider not reinventing the wheel and using the very common gem [acts_as_list](http://swanandp.github.com/acts_as_list/), which would make this as simple as `@project.higher_item` and `@project.lower_item`.